# Why does the TrueVault Dashboard always shows 0 documents in the Vaults?

Tags: truevault

I've created a document and I'm sure it is saved in the Vault too since I can fetch it, but the TrueVault dashboard shows me "0 DOCUMENTS Stored In TrueVault". Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

The Document count takes some time to load upon refresh of the dashboard. You should see the value updated after waiting some time (less than a minute). A revamp of the dashboard is on our roadmap.

Comment: Its been a couple of days since I created the doc in TrueVault. Still not showing. I know its there.